# Fading symbology at edges using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.2, line

A general problem for me with digitized material is that it can be too precise. Sometimes I just need to show a line or surface without sharp borders. I don't regularly need to visualize the exact extent of, say, a wetland to meter or dm level, only show that it exists in approximately that area.

Now I have lines (that I also have buffered 50 m) which I need to "smooth" at the edges. I want the center of the line/buffer to be strong in color. Further away from the center it should be more transparent, and eventually fade away.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

I have seen similar techniques described at [Ask a Cartographer](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.gateway) and I suspect that what you may be looking for is something like Tint Bands.

> Tint bands effectively look like a wide line symbol that is drawn just
>   inside the boundary of a [polygon].

This is one such [example](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/04/17/how-to-produce-tint-bands-for-boundaries/).

Alternatively, you may be looking for the "Fade to white background effect" that Aileen Buckley, Mapping Center Lead at Esri describes [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/10/14/fade-to-white-background-effect/).

> Buffer vignettes symbolize the interface between two areas. They are
>   often used to show the land-water interface by gradually fading blue
>   at the coast into white or vice versa. You can also use them to fade
>   the map out into a white background. These types of vignettes are
>   created using buffers that are symbolized in a special way.

Comment: I believe this could be applied to my case, although I don't work with borders/boundaries this time. I just have to buffer my lines on each side instead.